# How to add x number of 0 to result of COUNTIF MAX VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the formula below to add a unique number to cells that have matching data (duplicates)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,0))
```

at the moment it returns:
1
2
3
4
and so on

But I'd like it to return:
000001
000002
000003
000004
and so on?

Comment: `=TEXT(your_formula,"000000")`

Comment: Hi. This does not work, it changes the result of the formula to ALL 000001 all the way down the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try below-

```
=RIGHT("000000" & IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,0)),6)
```